# Прямая ссылка для перехода в приложение из браузера

Tags: android, deeplink

Сразу хочу сообщить, что я вообще 0 в программировании. Поэтому буду благодарен помощи "на пальцах". Код был взят на просторах Интернета. Сам не писал

Ситуация:
Нужно сделать личный "сервис" диплинков на своем сайте.

Была создана страница, которая определяет ОС (iOS и Android) и перенаправляет пользователя в приложение: http://letimdeshevo.ru/milocards.php

iOS работает, Android не могу настроить.

Код

```html
<script type="text/javascript"> // <![CDATA[
    if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1) || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPod') != -1) || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPad') != -1)) {
        
        document.location = "instagram://user?username=milocards";
        
    } // ]]>
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> // <![CDATA[
    if ( (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Android') != -1) ) {
        
       document.location = "https://www.instagram.com/milocards/";
      
       
    } // ]]>
</script>
```

В *document.location* вместо: https://www.instagram.com/milocards/

также пробовал

```
android-app://com.instagram.android/https/instagram.com/_u/milocards/
```

Но также не получается.

Скажите пожалуйста, как можно исправить?

Для iOS использовал простейшую инструкцию взятую из iPhone Hooks в API Instagram https://www.instagram.com/developer/mobile-sharing/
Для Android такой функции официально нет.(как я понял)

Пример работающего сервиса https://urlgeni.us/instagram/milocards
Если открывать с iPhone - перекидывает в приложение.
Если открывать с Android - перекидывает в приложение

Comment: Попробуйте: "instagram://com.instagram/milocards" или "instagram://com.instagram.www/milocards" или тоже самое только вместо: instagram:// -> content://

Comment: Валерий, спасибо, но к сожалению не работает :(

Comment: А не пробовали к ним на прямую обратиться? Если есть такая реализация для iPhone то такая скорее всего есть и для Android или в ближайшее время появиться.

Comment: Писать в Инстаграм не пробовал, они очень тяжело идут на контакт. Тех поддержка отвечает в 1 раз из 10.. могут месяцами обрабатывать запрос. К сожалению это не наш вариант)

Comment: Ну тоже вариант, а иначе можно 10-ть лет искать и ничего не найти. Есть ещё варик, найти сайт который умеет перекидовать в приложение и поковыряться в нём. Просмотрщик кода страницы и поиск в гугле, делают чудеса.

Comment: Я упомянул этот сайт в топике, но познаний моих не хватает для того чтобы вычленить оттуда что-то стоящее:) https://urlgeni.us/instagram/milocards

Comment: Та же ссылка, что у Вас для Йоси, работает и на Андроиде. Только если приложения нет на устройстве, то ничего не откроется, естественно.

Comment: Читайте официальную документацию на https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking. Вам нужно знать из манифеста приложения её зарегистрированные ссылки (откройте и посмотрите их)

Answer (score 3):

Нужно повесить intent filter на BROWSABLE.

В манифесте:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:scheme="https"
          android:host="instagram.com"
          android:pathPrefix="/milocards" />
</intent-filter>
```

В коде `Activity`:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.ac_job);

   final Intent intent = getIntent();
   final String action = intent.getAction();
   final String data = intent.getDataString();

   if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(action) && data != null) {
      // Здесь обрабатываем данные с сайта
   }
}
```

Более подробное описание, как что работает в этой [статье](https://medium.com/@1991chester/deep-links-fc993c7242af).

Comment: Я так предполагаю что ему нужно именно другое направление

Comment: Спасибо, попробую этот вариант. Только поясните пожалуйста, что за код Activity? Где его взять? Или как написать? файл AndroidManifest.xml создал в той же папке и вставил ваш код

Comment: Activity, это экран приложения.